# Access VBA find unmatched records in two tables

Tags: vba, ms-access, join

I have a complex query I've been struggling with. I've tried writing it several different ways. Nothing works. Either it fails or consumes too much memory and errors out.

Basically, I have

```
Table1
-F1
-F2
-F3
-F4
-F5
-F6
-F7
-F8

Table2
-F1
-F2
-F3
-F4
-F5
```

I need to take the concatenated value of F1+F2+F3+F4+F5 from Table1 one and make sure there is NO match for it in the concatenated value of F1+F2+F3+F4+F5 from Table2, where Table1.F6+Table1.F7 <> 'xxxxx' and Table1.F8 is empty.

But here's where it gets problematic...
I also, within the same query, need to make sure that not only is that first condition not met, but that 3 other conditions, where there are asterisks within that concatenated value of table 1 in certain places. Literal asterisks, not wildcards.

So let's say we concatenate the 5 fields into a column named TEMP in each table. I need this:

```
    Table1.TEMP <> Table2.TEMP 
    AND LEFT(Table1.TEMP,8) + "**" + Right(Table1.TEMP,2) <> Table2.TEMP
    AND LEFT(Table1.TEMP,9) + "**" + Right(Table1.TEMP,1) <> Table2.TEMP
    AND LEFT(Table1.TEMP,9) + "***" <> Table2.TEMP
    WHERE Table1.F6+Table1.F7 <> "xxxxx" AND Table1.F8 is empty
```

When those conditions are all met, I need to `update Table1.F9 = "x"`

I've tried to do this using a left join (unmatched query in access query builder), using OR statements for the 4 left joins. These tables have hundreds of thousands of lines and it was killing my machine. I've tried various other sql statements and had it error out due to lack of memory. I've tried a double recordset loop and it'll run till the end of time. I'm out of ideas. I have 6 similar queries I need to write.

Update: This is one of my attempted queries. The syntax is correct but will run for all eternity:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.TEMP = TABLE2.TEMP
OR LEFT(TABLE1.TEMP,8) + "**" + Right(TABLE1.TEMP,2) = TABLE2.TEMP
OR LEFT(TABLE1.TEMP,9) + "**" + Right(TABLE1.TEMP,1) = TABLE2.TEMP
OR LEFT(TABLE1.TEMP,9) + "***" = TABLE2.TEMP
SET TABLE1.F9 = "X"
WHERE TABLE2.TEMP IS NULL
AND TABLE1.F9 IS NULL
AND TABLE1.F7 + TABLE1.F8 = "XXXXX";
```

I hit "run" and it shows "run query" at the bottom. But 40 min later, the status bar hasn't filled up at all.

Update 2. I rewrote it as a SELECT statement and with just the top join statement (deleted the following 3), and it produces 28k rows. Is there a way to then, search through those 28k for the 2nd unmatched statement, and so on, using nested SQL statements? I'm not too familiar with complex SQL statements. I'm wondering if there's a way to break it up rather than doing the 3 OR's on the JOIN statement? I tried to add just the first OR statement in the join. So that I had 2 statements in the JOIN clause. And that killed it. It locks up access. That's with just one OR. So it can't handle the ORs in the JOIN clause.

Comment: What's the actual `JOIN` clause you're using? Your `JOIN` clause should be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or whatever the Access-SQL equivalent is) that defines the equalities; that will make the RHS of the join yield `NULL` results for every mismatch - then you make a `WHERE` clause that filters these `NULL` values in or out. Basically, what you want is an *exclusion* query, under an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, yes, I used a left join (that's what the access query builder automatically uses when you are doing an "unmatched" join. Then check for null on table2.tempcolumn. The problem is the 4 separate join clauses. I had it set up as left join on table1.temp = table2.temp OR left(LEFT(Table1.TEMP,8) + "**" + Right(Table1.TEMP,2) = table2.temp Or ... Or... for the 4 conditions above. And I don't think that's the right way to do it. It yields the correct results but it's wayyyyyy too slow. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Of course it's slow, you're joining on substrings/expressions. Join on indexed fields instead, and if Access doesn't support indexes then do whatever needs to be done to be able to join on actual fields. Including the actual query in your post would make it somewhat answerable... as it stands we can only guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: When I say slow, I mean, I'm not sure it's even doing anything. The status bar at the bottom that shows the query running, never changes. I've sat here for an hour and the status bar never increases. And I'm only working with a portion of the data. Temp column is indexed. I'll post one of the exact queries I've attempted. I'm just trying to figure out if there is a better when than 3 "OR's" on a join clause.

Comment: Temp column being indexed has no impact whatsoever, you're not using that index, you're slicing the column's content. Can you give us a [mcve] with some sample data?

Comment: updated with query

Comment: Temp column is 12 characters, numbers, letters, or asterisks.

Comment: It's usual for this to take ages: you're both using expressions in your join `LEFT(TABLE1.TEMP,8) + "**"` which keeps indexes from working properly, and you're using multiple `OR` clauses in your join, which need to be evaluated separately. If you're running this on say 10000 records, I wouldn't be surprised if it took multiple hours. And it's not strange for the process bar not to move.